# Starting a new thread on Exception using Uncaught Exceptional Handler

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, uncaughtexceptionhandler

A runnable task parses incoming xml file and is invoked from a different class. Sometimes the parsing may fail and throw an exception. The task should be running even when exceptions occur. I tried restarting the same task in a new thread using Uncaught exception handler. But wanted more ideas on that.

Class invoking thread : (invokes thread)

**It works fine to restart same task in new thread but probably handling exceptions without leading to a thread exit should be the way**

```
    Thread fileProcessThread = new Thread(FileProcessor);

    fileProcessorThread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
          {
             @Override
             public void uncaughtException (Thread arg0, Throwable arg1)
              {
                FileProcessor newObject = new FileProcessorTask();
                Thread t = new Thread(newObject);
                t.start();
              }
          });

    fileProcessor.start();
```

Task Class :

```
      public void run() {

        try {
              xmlparser.parse(incomingXmlFile);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                Thread.currentThread.getUncaughtExceptionalHandler().uncaughtException(Thread.currentThread(), e); 
                // this invokes uncaughtException to restart thread ?
            }
      }
```

I have a watch service (file directory scan) running, so I need the task all the time, even if thread terminates.

Comment: It is illogical to start this thread again in your situation. You should encapsulate parsing logic into your FileProcessor and handle xml parser exceptions appropriately in catch section. It has nothing to do with Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler; This one might have been handy if you could loose control against exception in such a thread.

Comment: I have a watch service (file directory scan) running on the thread, So I want this thread to keep continuing in spite of an exception occuring @AlexanderDrobyshevsky

Comment: Once it comes to ExceptionHandle which is set by getUncaughtExceptionalHandler, your thread will be destroyed in the end. You can start a thread only once. Therefore, you can either handle exceptions correctly inside running method or start a new thread when this one is dead. In the last case you should create a new thread.

Comment: That helps . I meant starting a new thread with the same process. I will try to catch parse exception right there or start a new thread with the process again. Got some clarity , thanks @AlexanderDrobyshevsky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an exception occurs and call reaches the uncaughtExceptionHandler, the state of the thread is Invalid to start again. So you need to create a new thread and start again.

Code from **Thread.start()**

```
// A zero status value corresponds to state "NEW".
if (threadStatus != 0)
   throw new IllegalThreadStateException();
```

However this could easily result in an infinite loop. (exception -> catch -> retry -> exception -> catch ...)
I recommend having a counter which stops the retries after a certain point.

```
Public class TestClass{
    static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    static class MyExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("caught");
            if (counter.get() == 3) {
                System.out.println("Reached Max. retries, exiting");
            } else {
                counter.incrementAndGet();
                new Thread(new MyTask()).start();
            }

        }
    }

    static class MyTask implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyExceptionHandler());
                System.out.println("slept");
                Thread.sleep(500);
                double d = 0 / 0;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new MyTask());
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

I've used `static AtomicInteger` but in your implementation probably have a common object which can be passed on from one thread to another and let that object have a counter.